# How is the 3D curvature of space represented in Riemann Curvature tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, simulations

I am trying to create a 3D VR General Relativity simulator using the river model like ScienceClic does here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wrwgIjBUYVc . As far as I know, for the rubber sheet representation you can simply just use flamm's parabloid but for the river model, you have to do it from the Riemann Curvature Tensor. My question is how do I get that from the Riemann Curvature Tensor, I thought I just define the origin as the core of the mass and from there get a vector of each point and multiply that by the Riemann Curvature Tensor but that doesn't work since I still get a tensor of Rank 3. Is there something simple I am missing, or do you have to do this in some other way?

EDIT: I am imposing the Schwarzschild metric for simplicity. Is that a reasonable assumption?

Comment: *How is the 3D curvature of space represented in Riemann Curvature tensor?* In the spatial components of that tensor.

Comment: @Ghoster So what exactly do I do with those spatial components to create the deformed gird?